# vba code to insert copied cells in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

i need to insert copied rows into another worksheet

i write this code and it doesn`t insert it, it gives me error.

```
Sub IsEmptyExample1()
    Dim wss As Sheets
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set ws = wss("Sheet1")
    wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 1 To wsLR
        Cells(x, 1).Select
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) = False Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(x).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("DE Portal LL").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Else

        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: i write this code and it doesn`t insert it, it gives me error ,,, Sub IsEmptyExample1()
Dim wss As Sheets,
Dim ws As Worksheet,

Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets,
Set ws = wss("Sheet1"),
wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row,
For x = 1 To wsLR,
Cells(x, 1).Select,

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) = False Then,

 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(x).Select,
    Selection.Copy,
    Sheets("DE Portal LL").Select,
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown,
 Else
 End If
 Next x
End Sub

Comment: It would be better to add the code from your comment to the post , also add the description of the error you get and be more concise about that you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this to learn [how to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). You had a few undeclared variables in your code. Your code was also copying a row and then trying to insert a new row onto a worksheet with that data. It would be better to just copy and paste to a new worksheet. Let me know if this helps:

```
Sub IsEmptyExample2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim Source As Range
    Set Source = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

    Dim DestRange As Range
    Set DestRange = Worksheets("DE Portal LL").Range("A1")

    Dim wsLR As Long
    wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim x As Long

    For x = 1 To wsLR
        If Cells(x, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Source(x, 1).Rows.EntireRow.Copy
            DestRange(x, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```